# ffmpeg screenshot files recursively

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

```
if [ -d "$1" ]; then
 echo If files are media, screenshots will be made to ~/Screenshots
 for media in $(find "${1%/}/"* -name '*.mkv' -or -name '*.mp4'); do ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel panic -ss 00:08:0.0 -i "$media"  -vframes 1 ~/Screenshots/$(basename "$media").screenshot1.png; done
 for media in $(find "${1%/}/"* -name '*.mkv' -or -name '*.mp4'); do ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel panic -ss 00:12:0.0 -i "$media"  -vframes 1 ~/Screenshots/$(basename "$media").screenshot2.png; done
 for media in $(find "${1%/}/"* -name '*.mkv' -or -name '*.mp4'); do ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel panic -ss 00:20:0.0 -i "$media"  -vframes 1 ~/Screenshots/$(basename "$media").screenshot3.png; done
fi
```

I'm trying to make 3 screenshots of all mkv/mp4 files to ~/Screenshots. But I keep failing and I can't find the source of the issue? It seems to fail only when there spaces in the name of the files but I quoted everything.

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: No error since I suppress everything. But I see that basename does not return a full file path ending with .mkv as it does when there is no space in the filenames. And I tried quoting it too. just create a ~/Screenshots folder and run this code you'll see

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from you iterating over the results of `find`. See [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) for more info. To prove it, just do the following from your media folder and see how the filenames get mangled:

```
for media in $(find -name '*.mkv' -or -name '*.mp4'); do echo "$media"; done
```

You can replace your `find` with globs, like so:

```
for media in "$1"/*.mp4; do stuff; done
for media in "$1"/*.mkv; do stuff; done
```

Or to make it simpler using brace expansion:

```
for media in "$1"/*.{mp4,mkv}; do stuff; done
```